# Abrir ficheiro local a partir do browser

Tags: html

Olá,

Qual é a maneira mais correta para abrir um ficheiro local (drive partilhada por rede) através do browser? O ficheiro deve ser aberto através de uma aplicação local(desktop) previamente instalado no PC. Exemplo: Link para um ficheiro excel, quando clicar deveria abrir o ficheiro no Excel(Programa)

```
<a href="file:///C:\Users\jsantos1991\Desktop\Teste.xlsx">Excel</a>
```

A questão é que desta forma aparece a janela a perguntar se quer abrir ou guardar e se por acaso for escolhida a opção guardar gera uma cópia do ficheiro.

Como consigo abrir através da aplicação local?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segundo a minha pesquisa o que eu preciso é de um esquema de URI
`ms-excel:`

Contudo consigo abrir a janela para iniciar aplicação mas depois gera me o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

**Você precisa usar o protocolo** `file:///` **(sim, são três barras)** se quiser vincular a arquivos locais.

```
<a href="file:///C:\Programs\sort.mw"> Link 1 </a>
<a href="file:///C:\Videos\lecture.mp4"> Link 2 </a>
```

**Estes nunca irão abrir o arquivo em seus aplicativos locais automaticamente**.

> Isso é por razões de segurança, e eu vou chegar a isso na última
>   seção. Se ele abrir, ele só será aberto no navegador. Se o seu
>   navegador pode exibir o arquivo, ele irá. Se não puder, provavelmente
>   perguntará se você deseja fazer o download.
>
> Alguns navegadores, como as versões modernas do Chrome, recusam-se a
>   passar do protocolo http para o protocolo de arquivos. Portanto, é
>   melhor abrir esse arquivo localmente usando o protocolo de arquivos,
>   se quiser fazer essas coisas.

**Por que ele fica preso sem `file: ///`?**

> **[A primeira parte de um URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax)** é o protocolo. Um protocolo é algumas letras, depois dois pontos e duas barras. `HTTP://` e `FTP://` são protocolos válidos; `C:/` não é e tenho certeza que nem mesmo
>   se parece com um.
>
> `C:/` também não é um endereço da web válido. O navegador pode
>   assumir que ele deve ser `http://c/` com uma porta em branco
>   especificada, mas isso falhará.
>
> Seu navegador pode não assumir que está se referindo a um arquivo
>   local. Tem poucas razões para fazer essa suposição, porque os sites
>   públicos geralmente não tentam vincular aos arquivos locais das
>   pessoas.
>
> Então, se você quiser acessar arquivos locais: diga para usar o
>   protocolo de arquivos.

**Por que três barras?**

> Porque é parte do esquema [URI do arquivo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). Você tem a opção de
>   especificar um host após as duas primeiras barras. Se você ignorar a
>   especificação de um host, ele apenas presumirá que você está se
>   referindo a um arquivo no seu próprio PC. Em outras palavras: `file:///C:/` etc é um atalho para `file:// localhost/C:/etc`.

**Esses arquivos ainda serão abertos no seu navegador e isso é bom**

> Seu navegador responderá a esses arquivos da mesma maneira que eles
>   responderam ao mesmo arquivo em qualquer lugar da Internet. Esses
>   arquivos **não serão** abertos em seu manipulador de arquivos padrão
>   (por exemplo, MS Word ou VLC Media Player), e você **não poderá**
>   fazer nada como pedir ao File Explorer para abrir a localização do
>   arquivo.

**Isso é extremamente bom para sua segurança.**

> Sites no seu navegador **não podem** interagir com o seu sistema
>   operacional muito bem. Se um bom site poderia dizer palestra.mp4 para
>   abrir em VLC.exe, um site mal-intencionado poderia dizer-lhe para
>   abrir virus.bat em CMD.exe. Ou pode apenas dizer ao seu PC para
>   executar alguns arquivos Uninstall.exe, ou abrir o File explorer um
>   milhão de vezes.
>
> Isso pode não ser conveniente para você, mas a segurança de HTML e
>   navegador não foi realmente projetada para o que você está fazendo. Se
>   você quiser abrir o lecture.mp4 no VLC.exe, considere escrever um
>   aplicativo de desktop.

Answer (score 0):

A forma "mais correta" é relativa, depende da linguagem que está usando.

Por exemplo, se você quiser usar html5, pode usar o código abaixo como **parte** da funcionalidade de upload:

```
<input type="file" name="arquivos" class="btn btn-success"/>
```

Lembrando que esse input apenas carrega a informação de onde o arquivo está na máquina do usuário, você ainda precisa carregar / enviar esse arquivo para o servidor, se é isso que você quer.

Se você não puder usar html5, mas estiver usando algum linguagem/framework web (como java com JSF, Struts, Spring...) pode usar algum scriptlet do framework.

Se quiser fazer sem uma linguagem de servidor apoiando, pode procurar scripts de upload de arquivo, em javascript com ou sem jquery (javascript file upload / jquery file upload).

Comment: Olá Reinaldo, repara que eu quero abrir o link com uma aplicação local. Exemplo um ficheiro Excel, quero criar um link que vai abrir esse ficheiro com o próprio Excel já instalado no PC, não quero fazer upload de documentos.

Comment: Entendi, e você já está fazendo como se deve, "file:///C:\1\2\3\file.xlsx". A questão agora é a segurança dos navegadores, Hoje em dia os navegadores tentam ao máximo bloquear a interação com o sistema operacional.

Comment: Esse link (em ingles) explica detalhadamente porque o navegador não vai deixar abrir um xlsx como se fosse um atalho para o microsoft excel, por exemplo. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246357/9691138